# muticast issue between two ubuntu machines

Tags: ubuntu, multicast

I have two ubuntu 16.04 machines (machine A and B) wich are connected by network cable. Machine A is creating multicasts. The multicasts do not reach machine B. Does anyone know, what the reason for this could be?

The following provides some forensic information:

Both machines do not have an active firewall, for example machine A shows:

```
root@linux:~# iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

The connected interfaces of the machine A and B are configured to transport multicast, for example machine A shows:

```
enp0s31f6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:1b:0e:c4:af:e1  
          inet addr:192.168.10.3  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::921b:eff:fec4:afe1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9221 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:25793 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:890075 (890.0 KB)  TX bytes:8214828 (8.2 MB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:f7100000-f7120000 

enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:1b:0e:ae:a2:fa  
          inet addr:169.254.1.2  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Memory:f7000000-f707ffff 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:106353 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:106353 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:20525233 (20.5 MB)  TX bytes:20525233 (20.5 MB)
```

Interface **enp0s31f6** is connected (RUNNING). The routing Table of A shows:

```
root@linux:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s31f6
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 enp1s0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s31f6
```

tcpdump on machine A shows outgoing multicast traffic:

```
15:47:37.420032 IP 192.168.10.3.2222 > 239.0.0.222.2222: UDP, length 327
15:48:37.415102 IP 192.168.10.3.2222 > 239.0.0.222.2222: UDP, length 327
15:49:37.417969 IP 192.168.10.3.2222 > 239.0.0.222.2222: UDP, length 327
```

wireshark on machine B does not show the multicast traffic.

Regards,

Guido

I made further investigations. I installed a switch between both ubuntu machines A and B and additionally I connected a mac laptop to this switch. The mac got an IP from machine B's DHCP server, so I was able to connect to the internet, because B is also connected to the internet and is playing the role of the gateway.

Once I started wireshark on the mac I could see the multicast packets while on B no packets could be detected. Additionally I started iperf on A and I could see all these generated packets on the mac, but not on B.

```
iperf -c 239.0.0.222 -p 2222 -u -T 32 -t 3 -i 1
```

Machine A (which is creating multicast packages)

```
root@linux:~# cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"
root@linux:~# uname -a
Linux linux 4.4.0-93-generic #116-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 21:17:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Maschine B

```
root@testserver:~# cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"
root@testserver:~# uname -a
Linux testserver 4.10.0-37-generic #41~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 6 22:42:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Machine B also has no firewall activated:

```
root@testserver:~# iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Machine B has the following network interfaces

```
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 74:d4:35:3d:13:14  
          inet Adresse:192.168.199.202  Bcast:192.168.199.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::e45b:3ea5:a1ca:2cf7/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:2541323 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:1958194 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:2907121035 (2.9 GB)  TX-Bytes:1743378563 (1.7 GB)
          Interrupt:20 Speicher:f0c00000-f0c20000 

enp12s0   Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:13:3b:0f:71:2c  
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::213:3bff:fe0f:712c/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:22 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX-Bytes:2721 (2.7 KB)

enp14s0   Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:13:3b:0f:71:2d  
          inet Adresse:192.168.30.1  Bcast:192.168.30.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::213:3bff:fe0f:712d/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:24903 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:28057 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:2617514 (2.6 MB)  TX-Bytes:3973717 (3.9 MB)

enp17s0   Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:13:3b:0f:6d:19  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)

enp19s0   Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:13:3b:0f:6d:1a  
          inet Adresse:192.168.40.1  Bcast:192.168.40.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)

enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:0a:cd:2f:f0:cc  
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::20a:cdff:fe2f:f0cc/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:1308 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX-Bytes:120880 (120.8 KB)

enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:0a:cd:2f:f0:cd  
          inet Adresse:192.168.20.1  Bcast:192.168.20.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::20a:cdff:fe2f:f0cd/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:59234 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:69110 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:6492424 (6.4 MB)  TX-Bytes:9395771 (9.3 MB)

enp5s0    Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:0a:cd:2f:f0:ce  
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::20a:cdff:fe2f:f0ce/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:31 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX-Bytes:3536 (3.5 KB)

enp6s0    Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:0a:cd:2f:f0:cf  
          inet Adresse:192.168.10.1  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::20a:cdff:fe2f:f0cf/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:822669 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:1701383 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:272743664 (272.7 MB)  TX-Bytes:2164337194 (2.1 GB)

lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife  
          inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
          inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:7895 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:7895 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:1222431 (1.2 MB)  TX-Bytes:1222431 (1.2 MB)
```

Machine B is connected via interface **enp6s0** and the Internet connection provides interface **eno1**

The network interfaces enp3s0 enp4s0 enp5s0 and enp6s0 are located on a 4 port network card.

The card contains RTL 8168 nics

Comment: Just in case: Machine A can ping machine B? `tcpdump` on machine B shows the ping packets?

Comment: Yes, A can ping B and vice versa

Comment: Huh. That would mean multicast packets arrive on B, but are dropped before you can `tcpdump` them. Which would mean on the driver level. That's really strange. Double check with `tcpdump -i enXX` on B that you *really* don't receive the, and there's no stupid mistake like choosing the wrong interface. Next step would be to confirm that something on B is the culprit: Can you replace B by some other machine, and see if you can receive the multicast packets  on that machine?

Comment: And I don't know how the network is physically setup, if they are not standing next to each other and you can see they are just connected with a simple cable, test with machine C (laptop etc.) in both locations. If there's a switch somewhere between the machines, the switch could be the cause.

Comment: I tried it without the switch first with the same failing result. Then I used the switch to set a mac laptop into the same segment and the mac laptop could see my multicasts (see my edits above). Because I am using RTL 8168 NICs it could be a reactivation of an old bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/258882

Comment: Yeah, my money is also on a driver bug.

Answer (score 1):

I "solved" the issue. The problem was, that Wireshark is obviously not possible to show multicast packets on a linux machine, if more than one interface is observed by this Wireshark instance at the same time. Once I sniffed only one interface with Wireshark, I could see the multicast packets. Perhaps it is a limitation of the RTL 8169 network card linux driver.

But I tried to scan the multicast packets, because I am facing the following issue: If a multicast packet enters interface X, I am not able to see it on an outgoing interface Y. I will request for an answer with a new thread.

Regards,

Guido

Answer (score 0):

Let show the configs of both of two server nodes.

Reference [**rfc5771**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5771)

The IP address of multicast can not be 192.168.10.3/24 as your configuration.

Normally, they must be in range **224.0.0.0/4** (from 224.0.0.0 to 239.255.255.255)

Look like: **224.168.10.3**

Comment: As mentioned in https://serverfault.com/questions/464160/unable-to-ping-multicast-ip it is obviously possible to use a unicast address as packet source. But I am honest, I did not read the RFC.